# Send HTTP POST followed by GET using same socket

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to create a Perl script that should send an HTTP POST request with XML data followed by a HTTP GET request using same socket.

I tried using [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent) but it seems it's creating a new socket for each request.

I also tried using [`IO::Socket`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Socket) but I'm not sure how to use it to send XML data.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $message = <<'XML';
<includeFilterSets>
  <filterSet>
    <filter>
      <filterName>VERSION_NAME</filterName>
      <operator>
        <name>In</name>
      </operator>
      <value>10.0u</value>
    </filter>
  </filterSet>
</includeFilterSets>
XML

my $webpage = "https://www.test.com/abc/cde.xml";
my $url     = "https://www.test.com";

my $ua        = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response1 = $ua->post($webpage, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $message);
my $response2 = $ua->get($url);
```

Comment: Please show your Perl code.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of LWP::UserAgent and search for keep_alive.

Comment: Your first instinct is right. `LWP` is the tool for the job. But more detail cannot be given without an example of what you've tried.

Comment: I have edited post to include the code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@SteffenUllrich` has suggested in a comment, you can force `LWP` to re-use a single TCP connection if you specify the `keep_alive` option in the constructor. Like this

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);
```

Comment: that tells the client to ask for keep alive; the server can still refuse to cooperate